# Should I write "it was blessed by a ritual" or "it was blessed through a ritual"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions

Should I write
 "it was blessed by a ritual" or
 "it was blessed through a ritual"?

Comment: Without more context it's hard to be definite but since the blessing is a result of a ritual which has (presumably) been conducted by a person, I'd use "it was blessed in a ritual".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please remember to provide full context when asking for a meaning, as many phrasings are equally valid, but may mean different things. In addition to *by* and *through*, I could plausibly use *in*, *with*, *via*, *after*, and perhaps *at*. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help]. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the meaning you are seeking to convey.

> "It was blessed by a ritual."

Implies that the ritual was the reason *it* was blessed. The reader's mind is kept purely on the ritual act itself, the ritual is the 'endpoint' there is no implicit extra idea associated with the phrase when you use the word *by*.

> "It was blessed through a ritual."

There is an additional idea implicit when you use the word *through* however. You are stating that the ritual was the agent of the blessing but not necessarily that the ritual was the total means of the blessing.

For example if the ritual was to some holy figure, then by stating that, *it* was blessed through a ritual, you are leaving space for the reader to imagine that the cause of the blessing was perhaps more than the ritual itself, the ritual was the means *through* which the blessing took place but not necessarily the sum total reason for the blessing.

When you use *by* however you are attributing the blessing more squarely as being a direct result of the ritual itself.